# Handle multi valued JSON response in Tivoli Directory Integrator V7.1.1

Tags: javascript, json

I have done my research and couldn't find any answer that was anywhere near to what I am looking for. Hence initiating a new thread.

I am trying to list all the WebSEAL log files in an assembly line using Tivoli Directory Integrator (TDI) and then intend to use only the log names as input to subsequent function. Code in TDI is written in JavaScript.

However, I am new to JSON and don't know how to handle multi valued response.

My response looks like following:

```
resultsEntry =
"message": "[{"id":"msg__webseald-int-dev.log","version":1470033259,"file_size":137647}, {"id":"request.log","version":1469425478,"file_size":104836}, {"id":"agent.log","version":1462348902,"file_size":0}, {"id":"config_data__int-dev-webseald-abcd.log","version":1470033258,"file_size":664433}, {"id":"referer.log","version":1462348902,"file_size":0}]",
"code": 200
```

I need values contained in all the "id" attributes. I have tried following, I get expected length but not the object.

```
var jsobj = fromJson(resultsEntry.getString("message"));
task.logmsg("jsobj is " + jsobj);
task.logmsg("jsobj length is " + jsobj.length);

This code snippet results in 

jsobj is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
jsobj length is 5
```

If I try following

```
task.logmsg("first id is " + jsobj.id[0]);
```

I get,

```
Exception occurrend while evaluating REST response com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=35, col=52: 'jsobj.id' is undefined and cannot be accessed as an array
```

Attempt to parse this JSON response somehow only returns first set of attributes

```
var resMessage = resultsEntry.getString("message");
var paramEntry = system.parseObject( "JSONPars", resMessage);
task.logmsg("paramEntry is "+paramEntry);

Above set of code snippet only prints 

paramEntry is {
"file_size": 137647.0,
"version": 1.470033259E9,
"id": "msg__webseald-int-spnego-dev.log"
}
```

How do I get an array or list of all the log files? Any help in this regard is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Gaurav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your parsing of the JSON attribute value is correct. As to accessing the parsed object, the suggestion above is spot-on: your `jsobj` variable references an array, so you'll need to apply the index to it directly before accessing the properties of contained objects. E.g. jsobj[i].id.

In the example script above, a new array named 'logs' is created and all the id values are added (pushed) to it. If you only want to log these values then you can replace

```
logs.push(jsobj[i].id)
```

with

```
task.logmsg(jsobj[i].id)
```

And as I wrote in your comment to my blog, the best place for TDI (SDI) questions is the TDI Forum:

https://groups.google.com/group/ibm.software.network.directory-integrator/topics?gvc=2

Hope this helps :)

-Eddie

Comment: Also thank you for exposing me to the TDI forum, it's highly enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Tivoli Directory Integrator V7.1.1 but i guess that all that you need is cycle.

```
var jsobj = fromJson(resultsEntry.getString("message")),
    logs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsobj.length; i++) {
    logs.push(jsobj[i].id);
}

console.log(logs);
```

Comment: Thank you Kison. Let me try this and then I can respond about how it behaves.